# Why is copy constructor called in call to std::vector::emplace_back()?

Tags: c++, c++11

It is my understanding that the purpose of `std::vector::emplace_back()` is specifically to **avoid** calling a copy constructor, and instead to construct the object directly.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct stuff
{
    unique_ptr<int> dummy_ptr;
    boost::filesystem::path dummy_path;
    stuff(unique_ptr<int> && dummy_ptr_,
          boost::filesystem::path const & dummy_path_)
        : dummy_ptr(std::move(dummy_ptr_))
        , dummy_path(dummy_path_)
    {}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    vector<stuff> myvec;

    // Do not pass an object of type "stuff" to the "emplace_back()" function.
    // ... Instead, pass **arguments** that would be passed
    // ... to "stuff"'s constructor,
    // ... and expect the "stuff" object to be constructed directly in-place,
    // ... using the constructor that takes those arguments
    myvec.emplace_back(unique_ptr<int>(new int(12)), boost::filesystem::path());

}
```

For some reason, despite the use of the `emplace_back()` function, this code fails to compile, with the error:

`error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' [...] This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'stuff::stuff(const stuff &)'`

**Notice that the compiler attempted to create (and use) the COPY CONSTRUCTOR**.  As I've discussed above, it's my understanding that the *purpose* of `emplace_back()` is to *avoid* the use of the copy constructor.

Of course, since the compiler is attempting to create and call the **copy** constructor, there's no way the code would compile **even if** I defined the copy constructor for `stuff`, because the `std::unique_ptr` cannot be used in a copy constructor.  Hence, I would very much like to avoid the use of a copy constructor (in fact, I need to avoid it).

(This is VS 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 on Windows 7 64-bit)

Why is the compiler generating, and attempting to use, the copy constructor, even though I am calling `emplace_back()`?

---

Note (in response to @Yakk's answer):

Explicitly adding the move constructor, as follows, resolves the problem:

```
stuff(stuff && rhs)
    : dummy_ptr(std::move(rhs.dummy_ptr))
    , dummy_path(rhs.dummy_path)
{}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 and earlier fails to write default move constructors for you.  Add a simple explicit move constructor to `stuff`.

A push or emplace back can cause stuff to be moved if it needs to reallocate, which in your case copies, as `stuff` has no move.

It is a msvc bug.

Comment: @dannissenbaum note that the move/copy is not called in your case, but must exist for the case where there was already existing content in the `vector` and it needed to resize.  The complie time instance of the method does not know it it being called on an empty `vector`, so it must handle all code paths.